# Using Properties Window in runtime to customize windows form controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

Is there a way to use visual studio design-time `Properties Window` at runtime to customize a specific `Control` such as `DataGridView`?

Some thing like image below needed to enable user to customize controls on a `Form` by changing properties of them.

[image]

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Visual Studio's `Properties` window is exposed in WinForms as the `PropertyGrid` control - so the answer to OP's question is **yes**.

Comment: The `PropertyGrid` is a standard control. You can add one to your Form or create it at run-time. You can use the `SelectedObject` property to associate it to a *living* control ad it will populate automatically.

Comment: @Jimi You should post that as an answer. I've reached my karma-limit for the day anyway.

Comment: Thank you @Dai and jimi for reply. That is what I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [PropertyGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a standard control. You can add one to your Form or create it at run-time.
In the ToolBox, it's usually found in the `All Windows Forms` cathegory, or using the search tool.
It can be fully customized and supports transparent colors.

You can use the [SelectedObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.selectedobject?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to associate it to an existing control and it will populate automatically (this property can also be set at design-time).

The `PropertyGrid` can then be used to change the associated control's properties at run-time.

```
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = this.dataGridView1;
```

[image: Property Grid Control]