# Is there a way to get speficic object from a generic list of objects

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, user-controls

I want to populate a panel with usercontrols that inherit from an abstract usercontrol. The only common superclass they have is control.

The code to populate the BaseShape and BaseFractal is a generic method that ask for a list of controls to populate it self with. I want to create an object on the field next to the panel with the type they clicked on the preview with the properties of the usercontrol properties. I cant call upon the properties because BaseShape and BaseFractal don't have them common. I thought of creating a superclass with all these properties so that i can change them and ignore the properties i don't wanne change. Is there any other way of doing this beside the idea of creating a superclass with all the propeties in them?

[image: Design drawing app]

```
private void PopulatePanel(List<Control> controls, Panel panel, int controlsPerRow = 3)
       {
           if (Utility.Utility.IsNullOrDefault(controls) || Utility.Utility.IsNullOrDefault(panel) || controlsPerRow <= 0) return;
           panel.Controls.Clear();
           int widthBetweenControls = (int)(panel.Width * 0.05);
           int heightBetweenControls = (int)(panel.Height * 0.05);
           int heighthBetweenSideControl = (int)(panel.Height * 0.1);
           int widthBetweenSideControl = (int)(panel.Width * 0.1);
           int yCoord = heighthBetweenSideControl;
           int widthControl = (int)((panel.Width - 2 * widthBetweenSideControl - widthBetweenControls * (controlsPerRow - 1)) / controlsPerRow);
           int heightControl = (int)((panel.Height - 2 * heighthBetweenSideControl - heightBetweenControls * (controlsPerRow - 1)) / (controlsPerRow-1));
           for (int i = 0; i <= controls.Count / controlsPerRow; i++)
          {
               int xCoord = widthBetweenSideControl;
               for (int j = 0; j < controlsPerRow; j++)
               {
                   if (j + (i * controlsPerRow) == controls.Count) return;
                   Control c = controls.ElementAt(j + (i * controlsPerRow));
                   c.Width = widthControl;
                   c.Height = heightControl;
                  c.Location = new Point(xCoord, yCoord);
                panel.Controls.Add(c);
                xCoord += (j == controlsPerRow) ? (widthBetweenSideControl) : (widthBetweenControls + widthControl);
            }
            yCoord += (i >= controls.Count / controlsPerRow) ? (heighthBetweenSideControl) : (heightBetweenControls + heightControl);
        }
    }

    private void ShapeButon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();
        foreach(Shape t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Shape)))
        {
            BaseShape bs = ShapeFactory.CreateInstance(t);
            controls.Add(ShapeFactory.CreateInstance(t));
        }
        PopulatePanel(controls, selectPanel, 3);
    }
```

Comment: Use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel) to layout your controls and a [PropertyGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid) control to show the properties of the control selected. See the notes here about the latter: [Using Properties Window in runtime to customize windows form controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53473570/7444103).

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't understand this sentence: *"I want to create an object on the field next to the panel with the type they clicked on the preview with the properties of the usercontrol properties. "*

Comment: Create a common base class for BaseShape and BaseFractal with an abstract method to return the list of properties.  In BaseShape and BaseFractal, implement that method to return the appropriate list of properties for that type.